# How can I create a sitemap in next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to add a sitemap to my next.js website. I added the following code to `server.js`

```
server.get('/sitemap.xml',  (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        root:'./',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
        }
      };

    return res.status(200).sendFile('sitemap.xml', options)
});
```

The `sitemap.xml` file is at the root folder, i.e. the same location as the `server.js` file. When I run it locally using `node server`, and go to `http://localhost:5000/sitemap.xml` it works correctly. When I upload the files to the server, I get a `not found` error from the server.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I add a sitemap using nextjs?

Comment: Hi Jessica. How are you running your node app on the server? And one more thing, have you checked the file permissions for sitemap.xml?

Comment: One thing is that this is a route that is dynamic not an actual file. So if you are just deploying static content then this will not work you'll need to have a full nextjs server in production too.

One thing, I think that next.js supports static files under the public folder so if you move the sitemap there it may just work as a static file.

Answer (score 2):

Probably just move the `sitemap.xml` file under the public folder such as `public/sitemap.xml` and then delete this custom dynamic route.

[Next.js static file serving documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

Comment: This answer should work. I just deployed a Next.js app using the same method. Upvoted.

Comment: I don't have a public folder, I have a .next folder

Comment: Make one then. The .next folder is build output so don&#39;t put anything in there and don&#39;t commit it to source control.